# Connection refused error while accessing my server with AWS elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-ip, namecheap

I have followed all these below mentioned steps

1. Create an Elastic IP and point to the Amazon EC2 instance.
2. Goto service Route 53, create a ‘A’ record and point to the Elastic IP.
3. In Route 53, copy the Amazon NS (name server) urls and paste in Namecheap nameserver area.

But after 48 hours my domain name still not reachable. Even i cant access my server with AWS elastic IP.

I have created an elastic IP in AWS for my instance. And my public DNS address got updated.

I contacted Namecheap support team, they said the IP i pointed my domain to is giving them connection refused error. They are getting a "|52.25.76.52|:80... failed: Connection refused." error.

I have referred this [reference article](http://www.mkyong.com/server/namecheap-domain-name-and-amazon-ec2/) for configuring AWS & Namecheap

Pls help me to fix this

Comment: Have you changed your security group to allow HTTP from 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, it already allows HTTP, TCP and MySQL/Aurora in security group of this instance.

Comment: And you're sure the webserver is responding properly?  Are you able to SSH in and curl it from localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what NameCheap have said it could be a security group set up error, no internet gateway in your VPS, something wrong with your routing, web server not set up right, or one of a thousand other things you could've done wrong.

I wrote an [AWS setup guide](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/), follow it through and you may be able to work it out. If you can't figure it out you're probably going to have to pay someone to look at it for you, unless someone gets really lucky and guesses what you've set up wrong. It's probably something minor but critical.